# Minted, setstretch and font size

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing, minted, setspace

I'm using `minted` package. My problem is `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}` line. I do need this line stretch, but I don't want it to affect code sources generated by `minted`.
How can this be done?
Also, I would like to be able to change font size used by code listings independently from rest of document. I think I want 10 or 11pts for code listings and 12pt for rest of the text.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{java}
public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could insert the following code in your document's preamble, after loading the `minted` package:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\singlespacing%
    \fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont}
```

Alternatively, you could start each `minted` environment with the following options: `baselinestretch=1` and `fontsize=\footnotesize`. The latter works because if you set the main font size to be 12pt, then `\footnotesize` will switch to a font size that's 2pt smaller; if you want your code to be typeset in 11pt (and the main font size is still 12pt), you should use the command `\small` instead of `\footnotesize`.

Comment: Or, as it was recommended in another topic, `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\begin{singlespacing*}}` and `\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{singlespacing*}}` which may produce better spacing around the environment.

Comment: @egreg: Your suggestion would seem to be more in conformance with the (slighly terse) explanation given in the `setspace` package. I suppose which method is "better" for the OP depends largely on how much whitespace the OP would like to get above and below each `minted` environment.

Comment: @egreg I tried your solution but it seems not to work. Should I load any additional package? (do I need etoolbox?)

Comment: @POliveira Yes, you need `etoolbox`

Comment: @egreg Right, I tried your solution and I was given an `unknown environment` error. As far as I could understand, the environment would be called `singlespace` instead of `singlespacing`. Just one more thing, are the asterisks needed at the end of the environment's name? If so, what for? Thanks

Comment: @POliveira Sorry, but I can't follow you. Probably a new question is better.

Comment: FYI: Still working with the minted version 2.0 package.

Comment: **Note**: this may not work with other minted commands/environments e.g. [`\inputminted`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/650090/250119).

Answer (score 31):

`\setminted{fontsize=\small,baselinestretch=1}`

Enjoy

Comment: I guess this should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 14):

A bit late to the party, but defining an environment such as

```
\newminted{java}{fontsize=\footnotesize}
```

works too.  Then all

```
\begin{javacode}...\end{javacode}
```

will have font size set to footnotesize.