# How to change overall font size of minted?

Tags: fontsize, minted

While using minted I can change font size ([Change font size in minted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399340/change-font-size-in-minted)) on each individual place using the `fontsize=\footnotesize`:

```
\begin{listing}
\inputminted[fontsize=\footnotesize]{javascript}{file.js}
\end{listing}
```

Can I set this once for the entire document?

Answer (score 12):

With `\setminted{fontsize=...}` you can set the default font size for all your `minted` environments.

If you explicitly indicate a font size in a single `minted` environment, it overrides the default.

I think your question is a duplicate of [Minted, setstretch and font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35546/minted-setstretch-and-font-size?rq=1), the most correct answer to that question is [Himura's one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376818/101651).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\setminted{fontsize=\footnotesize}
\begin{document}
\noindent\verb|\footnotesize| is the default font size:
\begin{minted}{objc}
if you do not specify another fontsize
your minted environment will be footnotesize
\end{minted}
\begin{minted}{objc}
all your minted evronments will be footnotesize
\end{minted}
Unless you specify another font size:
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\large]{objc}
this is large
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]