# How do I reduce line spacing in listing using `\inputminted` command?

Tags: listings, line-spacing, minted

I use for listings `minted` package, and can reduce line spacing in case of using `minted` environment. But can't reduce listing line space in case of using external source code file via `\inputminted` command. How can I deal with it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

Try to reduce line spacing with inputminted command

\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\linespread{0.15}}
\inputminted[breaklines=true]{c}{main.cpp}

Reduce line spacing with minted environment use.

\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\linespread{0.15}}
\begin{minted}{cpp}
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++)
     printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

The content of `main.cpp` and `minted` environment the same.

[image]

Comment: You probably copied that code from the first answer in [fontsize - Minted, setstretch and font size - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35546/minted-setstretch-and-font-size). In that case, try using the second answer to see if it works.

Comment: Was trying to find answer by myself but was not successful in it, next time will search more carefully. Thanx, `\setminted{baselinestretch=0.5}` works well.